# draw circle in java by midpoint algorthim

Tags: java, opengl, graphics

I am trying to draw a circle in java by using the midpoint algorithm  but this code does not give me a well-defined circle and some points are down and some others up so I wanna I well-defined circle in this

```java
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import assginment4.Graphics;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.input.Mouse;
    
    
public class input {

    
    void circle (i`nt xc, int yc, int r`) //xc and yc is the center of circle and r is radius
    {
        int x,y,d;
        d=1-r;
        x=0;
        y=r;
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        while(x<=y)
        {
            
            glVertex2f(x+xc, y+yc);
            glVertex2f(x+xc, -y+yc);
            glVertex2f(-x+xc, y+yc);
            glVertex2f(-x+xc, -y+yc);
            
            glVertex2f(y+xc, x+yc);
            glVertex2f(y+xc, -x+yc);
            glVertex2f(-y+xc, x+yc);
            glVertex2f(-y+xc, -x+yc);
            if(d>0)
            {
                x+=1;
                y-=1;
                d+=1+2*x+1-2*y-1;
            }
            else
            {
                x++;
                d+=2*x+1;
            }
        }
        glEnd();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
            Display.setTitle("Input Demo");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }
       
        
        
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
                Display.destroy();
                System.exit(0);
            }
            

            input d1 = new input();
            
                
                if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                    d1.circle(Mouse.getX(), 480-Mouse.getY(), 50);
                
                }
                
                
                Display.update();
                Display.sync(60);
            
        }
        
        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

also, I want this circle not to be filled with the color

also, can anyone help me and tell me how to draw the ellipse by the same algorithm

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with the order of the vertices of the 2nd quad. You have to swap the 3rd and 4th vertex coordinate:

```java
glVertex2f(y+xc, x+yc);
glVertex2f(y+xc, -x+yc);
glVertex2f(-y+xc, -x+yc);
glVertex2f(-y+xc, x+yc);
```

If you want to draw a circular outline, you need to use the [primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) type `GL_POINTS` instead of `GL_QUADS`:

```java
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
while (x <= y) {
    
    glVertex2f(x+xc, y+yc);
    glVertex2f(x+xc, -y+yc);
    glVertex2f(-x+xc, y+yc);
    glVertex2f(-x+xc, -y+yc);
    
    glVertex2f(y+xc, x+yc);
    glVertex2f(y+xc, -x+yc);
    glVertex2f(-y+xc, -x+yc);
    glVertex2f(-y+xc, x+yc);

    if (d > 0) {
        x += 1;
        y -= 1;
        d += 1 + 2*x + 1 - 2*y -1;
    }
    else {
        x ++;
        d += 2*x + 1;
    }
}
glEnd();
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it work and give me well-defined one

Comment: do you know what i need to add to make it over instead of circle

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the APIs you are using but it seems the rough edges of the circle are because is that you use integers instead of doubles or floats so the points are not very precise.

Note that I don't quite understand what is happening in circle. What does d represent?